# Is it possible to live a life in which we never ever tell a lie?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, humanism

How will we explain such a schema of life in which we never ever tell a lie according to the  philosophical point of view?

Comment: How would you know? In order to be always in truth.. you'd need to be omniscient. As an example let me ask you this.. who discovered America?

Comment: A state of affairs precluding both war and economic competition might foster honesty and truthfulness. And you don't need to be omniscient to be perfectly truthful, because telling lies always involves intent to deceive. Nevertheless, the reason people argue over who discovered America is purely political and economical, besides that so many different prehistorical groups were involved over a very long period of time. As for the 'philosophical fact' point of view, there would be no need for speculative persuasion. See *The Works of William Chillingworth*, chapter V, page 300 (free on google).

Comment: I made an edit. You may roll this back or continue editing. If you have more context for the question that might help someone with an answer. For example, are you reading something now that made you think of this question.  Regardless, welcome to this SE!

Comment: @Richard To avoid saying things that are not true, you don't need to be omniscient - you just need to keep your mouth shut when you don't know something. And saying things that are not true is not the same as lying - lying involves the wish to deceive.

Comment: One would be keeping one's mouth shut permanently... Because truth is a slippery thing. My dad says the scar on my top lip is from a broken dummy. My mum from a tooth.. both are adamant they're right. It matters to me that one of them is lying.. though not deliberately.. the reason humanity doesn't live in peace... Is proof that unintentional lies are still lies.. is there a God? Really? What to tell your kids then?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you can.**

But then not many will believe that. So is it then false by consensus?

Yet there *are* many things only true because a majority believes it...

The truth is the Truth is not completely defined, and by extension the Lie not either.

https://plato.stanford.edu/search/searcher.py?query=truth